# is DialogFlow HIPAA compliant?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

is GCP DialogFlow HIPAA compliant? I see other low level NLP/ML services are HIPAA compliant which DialogFlow might be using but DialogFlow itself is not tagged as HIPAA complaint.

Comment: Travis' answer is correct. Even though DialogFlow is HIPAA compliant, your implementation might not be. You need to follow the guidelines to ensure compliance end-to-end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. See the Covered Products section here:

- [HIPAA Compliance on Google Cloud Platform > Covered Products](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/#covered-products)
- [Full HIPAA Compliance PDF](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/resources/hipaa_compliance_guide_gcp.pdf)

---

Some Additional Context, based on discussion in comments:

Due to the nature of HIPAA, all HIPAA-compliant services everywhere have the potential to be used in ways that would break compliance. The user is always responsible for using these services properly according to the documentation.

Comment: The PDF says "It is important to note that there is no certification recognized by the US HHS for HIPAA compliance and that complying with HIPAA is a shared responsibility between the customer and Google. Specifically, HIPAA demands compliance with the Security Rule,the Privacy Rule, and the Breach Notification Rule. Google Cloud Platform supports HIPAA compliance (within the scope of a Business Associate Agreement) but ultimately customers are responsible for evaluating their own HIPAA compliance." 
I am no legal expert but is this  same as having a HIPAA compliance?

Comment: Some other similar products like Amazon LEX, explicitly say that they are not HIPAA compliant yet.

Comment: @Hrushikesh Due to the nature of HIPAA, all HIPAA-compliant services everywhere have the potential to be used in ways that would break compliance. The user is always responsible for using these services properly.

Comment: Right, so Lex is not compliant regardless of how clever your implementation. DialogFlow is compliant as long as you follow HIPAA guidelines within your implementation. At the end of the day, HIPAA is a legal specification, not a technical one, so there isn't a technical solution that can protect you from yourself.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the response.